# Why is my Python while loop repeating twice even if I provide a response that should break the loop?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

The following while loop repeats once even when the condition is false. I think it has something to do with the `return()` statements but I'm a noob so I'm not quite sure what I'm not understanding. Thanks for any help! Self-teaching is murky waters lol

```
def playAgain():
    success = False
    while success == False:
        againChoice = input("\nWould you like to play again? (\"yes\" or \"no\")\n").lower()

        if againChoice == "yes":
            success = True
            return(False)
            
        elif againChoice == "no":
            success = True
            return(True)
        
        else:
            print("\nTry that again, please.")
```

While running the loop, it will ask me the "play again" question twice even if I provide either correct response the first time. Only the second response ever "sticks". Here's an example of the output I get:

> Would you like to play again? ("yes" or "no")
> yes
>
> Would you like to play again? ("yes" or "no")
> no

The loop then breaks and the function returns the result associated with my second response regardless of my first response.

I call this function inside of another `while` loop `if` statement (which subsequently breaks the other loop) but that doesn't seem to be the problem because the repeat occurs before this function ends. Also, I know I could just `break` the loop but this is more of a pedagogical exercise so I'd like to understand what's happening.

Edit:

Here's where I call `playAgain()`.

```
compNum = random.randint(1,100)
guessed = False
while guessed == False:

    userGuess = guess()

    if userGuess == compNum:
        win()
        guessed = playAgain() # Right here
        if guessed ==False:
            compNum = random.randint(1,100)

    elif userGuess < compNum:
        tooCold()

    elif userGuess > compNum:
        tooHot()
```

Edit 2:
It is also called here.

```
def win():
    print("\nYou got it!\n")
    playAgain()
```

Edit 3:

Solved in the comments - I was calling the function twice as you can see above. Somehow missed this

Thanks to everyone who helped my blind self!

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question and put there part of the code where you call `playAgain()` ?

Comment: *"the repeat occurs before this function ends"* - can you say more about why you think this? Can you rule out the possibility that the function ends but is immediately called again?

Comment: Why do you have parentheses around the return value? They're redundant, so remove them.

Comment: There is nothing here that would make the loop repeat.  The problem must be in the actual call to this function (which you did not show us).

Comment: I've added the call as requested. Sorry, I added print statements to try and find where the error was happening and nothing outside the original function seemed to be the source. Thanks for the parenthesis comment - I'm new enough that I didn't even notice it.

Comment: Does the function `win()` itself call `playAgain()`, by any chance?

Comment: Yes, sorry:
  
def win():  
    print("\nYou got it!\n")  
    playAgain()

Comment: OH - That's the issue, I think. Obviously, it seems. Thank you. I feel dumb now! lol

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided seems to work fine if call alone. Try to define `playAlong` and call it, you'll see it works as expected.

Probably, the problem is within the other loop that you mentioned. Please, update your question with the rest of the code.

Comment: You are correct that the function seems to work fine on its own. I've added the additional code, thank you!